# Using Node.js to find the value of Bitcoin on a webpage at real time

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I'm trying to make a .js file that will constantly have the price of bitcoin updated (every five minutes or so). I've tried tons of different ways to web scrape but they always output with either null or nothing. Here is my latest code, any ideas?

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var url = 'https://blockchain.info/charts/';
var port = 9945;
function BTC() {
    request(url, function (err, res, body) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);

        var a = $(".market-price");
        var b = a.text();
        console.log(b);
    })
    setInterval(BTC, 300000)
}

BTC();
app.listen(port);
console.log('server is running on '+port);
```

It successfully says what port it's running on, that's not the problem. This example (when outputting) just makes a line break every time the function happens.

UPDATE:
I changed the new code I got from Wartoshika and it stopped working, but im not sure why. Here it is:

```
function BTCPrice() {
    request('https://blockchain.info/de/ticker', (error, response, body) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(body);
        var value = (parseInt(data.USD.buy, 10) + parseInt(data.USD.sell, 10)) / 2;

        return value;
    });

};
console.log(BTCPrice());
```

If I have it console.log directly from inside the function it works, but when I have it console.log the output of the function it outputs undefined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use a JSON api to get the current bitcoin value instead of an HTML parser. With the JSON api you get a strait forward result set that is parsable by your browser.

Checkout [Exchange Rates API](https://blockchain.info/api/exchange_rates_api)

Url will look like `https://blockchain.info/de/ticker`

Working script:

```
const request = require('request');

function BTC() {

    // send a request to blockchain
    request('https://blockchain.info/de/ticker', (error, response, body) => {

        // parse the json answer and get the current bitcoin value
        const data = JSON.parse(body);
        value = (parseInt(data.THB.buy, 10) + parseInt(data.THB.sell, 10)) / 2;

        console.log(value);
    });
}

BTC();
```

Using the value as callback:

```
const request = require('request');

function BTC() {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        // send a request to blockchain
        request('https://blockchain.info/de/ticker', (error, response, body) => {

            // parse the json answer and get the current bitcoin value
            const data = JSON.parse(body);
            value = (parseInt(data.THB.buy, 10) + parseInt(data.THB.sell, 10)) / 2;
            resolve(value);
        });
    });
}

BTC().then(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Could you do a quick run through on how to go about doing this? I'm somewhat new to node (I've only really learned python), but I'm interested and I want to finish this.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was stressing about this so much!

Comment: I edited my question as to add a new question, could you look into it for me? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer stated, you should really use an API. You should also think about what type of price you want to request. If you just want a sort of index price that aggregates prices from multiple exchanges, use something like the CoinGecko API. Also if you need real-time data you need a websocket-based API, not a REST API.

If you need prices for a particular exchange, for example you're building a trading bot for one or more exchanges, you;ll need to communicate with each exchange's websoceket API directly.  For that I would recommend something like the [Coygo API](https://www.coygo.app/api.html), a node.js package that connects you directly to each exchange's real-time data feeds. You want something that doesn't add a middleman since that would add latency to your data.